# Output of program does not match formula (Probability problem)

Tags: python, probability

I'm trying to solve this problem for school. I wrote some code for it, however I am not sure if my code is correct because when I checked website (linked below) for the formula to solve the problem, my output does not align with the answers of the formula, I was wondering what I am missing or if I am doing something wrong.

This is the link with the problem and the mathematical solution:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1110006/n-players-throw-a-die-and-get-score-for-each-pair-who-throw-the-same-number

I only have the mean so far because I didn't bother to get the variance seeing that the results of the mean were different.

This is the code:

```
import random

dice = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

def dice_a (n, sims):
    scores= []
    sim_counter = 0

    scores_ctr = {}
    
    for x in range(n // 2): 
        scores_ctr[x + 1] = 0
    
    while sim_counter != sims:
        score = 0

        rolls = random.choices(dice, k=n)
        pairs = {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0}

        for x in rolls:
            pairs[x] += 1 
            if pairs[x] == 2:
                score += 1
                pairs[x] = 0

        scores.append(score)
        scores_ctr[score] += 1
        sim_counter += 1

    mean = 0
    for x, y in scores_ctr.items():
        mean += x * (y/1000)

    return mean

print(dice_a(7, 1000))
```

Hope to get some help!

Thank you so much!

Comment: Your code is displaying the mean of a random set of values, but not the values themselves. So you have no way to tell if the result is off, and if so why. Put in some `print` calls to show intermediate results, and keep the value of `rolls` small while testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is in the way you calculate the number of pairs with the same dices.

Let's say you have the next dice throws:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

The way you calculate it right now your number of pairs and the total score will be 3, though the correct one is 21. You just found the next pairs:

1. The first and the second players.
2. The third and the fourth.
3. The fifth and the sixth.

And it's wrong because there are more pairs with the same dice throws. Like:

1. 1st and 2nd.
2. 1st and 3rd.
3. 1st and 4th.
   ...

The correct way to calculate it will be using [combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination).

Or in the code:

```py
for x in rolls:
    pairs[x] += 1
for val in pairs.values():
    if val > 1:
        score += math.factorial(val) // (2 * math.factorial(val - 2))
if score not in scores_ctr: 
    scores_ctr[score] = 0
scores_ctr[score] += 1
```

Comment: This worked! However, I was wondering if you could explain what the code does. I don't quite understand how you did it. I'm quite new to python

Comment: I counted every dice throw and stored it in a dictionary, as you did. Then we need to calculate how many pairs we have for each possible dice value. Obviously, there can not be any pairs with just 1 or 0 throws for the specific value, so the `if` part. Then we just use the combination formula mentioned in the answer. We need to know how many combinations of 2 elements there are for our dice value. For example, we have 2 throws with value 2, so `2! / (2! * (2-2)!) = 1` pair, or we have 3 throws with value 2 then: `3! / (2! * (3-2)!) = 3` pairs. Then we just sum it up to the total score.

Comment: Why is my code incorrect? Why must you count all the possible combinations? ```[1, 1, 1]``` I thought this would only be one point, because you disregard the other piece?

Comment: In the link in your question, there is this condition: "For every pair of players who throw the same number, the group scores 1 point". For *every* pair. How many different pairs in the `[1, 1, 1]` results? Let's count. (1st player, 2nd player), (1st player, 3rd player), (2nd player, 3rd player). Total of 3 different pairs. And you just counted the (1st player, 2nd player) pair by disregarding the 3rd player's throw.